# I want spinner to display numbers properly

Tags: javascript, spinner

I have 2 questions:

Question 1: I have a spinner function and I have one slight problem with it. If a user types in 00000009 or 00021 in the spinner for example, if the user clicks away from the spinner, it will still display 00000009 or 00021 in the spinner. What I want is that if something like this happens, then what I want is that when the user clicks away, I want the spinner to display it as 9 or 21 rather than 00000009 or 00021. I don't know how to do this though. Does anyone know how to overcome this:

Question 2: If I used backspace to remove a number from a spinner and that is left with a blank spinner, what needs to be done so that if I click away from the spinner, the last number in the spinner re-appears in the spinner?

My main spinner function:

```
    function Spinner(elem,min, max){
                this.elem = elem;
                this.elem.value = min;
                this.min = min;
                this.max = max;
                this.timer;
                this.speed = 150; //milliseconds between scroll values
                var selfO = this;

                this.elem.onkeyup = function(){
                    var regex = /^[0-9]*$/;
                    if(!regex.test(selfO.elem.value)){
                        selfO.elem.value = selfO.elem.value.substring(0,selfO.elem.value.length-1);
                        return;
                    }
                    selfO.validateValue();
                }


            this.validateValue = function(){
                if(Number(selfO.elem.value) > selfO.max) {selfO.elem.value = selfO.max;}
                if(Number(selfO.elem.value) < selfO.min) {selfO.elem.value = selfO.min;}
            }

            this.stopSpinning = function(){
                clearTimeout(selfO.timer);
            }

            this.spinValue = function(dir){
                selfO.elem.value = Number(selfO.elem.value) + dir;
                selfO.validateValue();
                selfO.timer = setTimeout(function(){selfO.spinValue(dir);},selfO.speed);
            }

        };

 window.onload=function(){
            //create the Spinner objects
            var SpinnerHours = new Spinner(document.getElementById('txtHours'),0,23);
}
```

Comment: I thought I include the bottom function to help you understand it a bit better

Answer (score 3):

To return a number like 00000009 as 9 use `parseInt();`

```
alert( parseInt(000000009, 10) );  // returns 9
```

As pointed out by [Jonathan Lonowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15031/jonathan-lonowski) The second parameter is the radix.

The radix parameter is used to specify which numeral system to be used, for example, a radix of 16 (hexadecimal) indicates that the number in the string should be parsed from a hexadecimal number to a decimal number.

If the radix parameter is omitted, JavaScript assumes the following:

- If the string begins with "0x", the radix is 16 (hexadecimal)
- If the string begins with "0", the radix is 8 (octal). This feature is deprecated
- If the string begins with any other value, the radix is 10 (decimal)

Comment: With leading 0s, you'll want to pass a radix of 10 to avoid octal evaluation -- `parseInt("000000009", 10)`. Yours example works as is cause it's already a number.

Comment: Where shall I insert the parse insert in my code, I tried in the bottom function parseInt(0),parseInt(23); but that didn't work

Comment: Good to know, just read up about the radix parameter, never knew about it or had use for it... either way I learned something new so +1 and updated my answer.

Comment: @user1050384 You can use it inside your `onkeyup` function, before the `return;` -- `selfO.elem.value = parseInt(selfO.elem.value, 10);`

Comment: try parseInt(self0.elem.value)

Comment: That has worked brilliantly, thank you john, jeff and koolkabin, I posted an extra question below because I forgot to put it in, I just wanted to know if a spinner is blank, how can I get the spinner to display the previous number

Comment: actually I just realised that it only works in some browsers not in all browsers

Comment: I just tested in FF, IE, and Chrome, and parseInt works the same in all and produces the value of 9.  As far as your other question I don't know exactly how your spinner function is used but you can create a variable called `prevNum` and in your `onkeyup` event before the `return;` add `prevNum = selfO.elem.value` then depending where you want to check if its blank use something like `if (selfO.elem.value == "") selfO.elem.value = prevNum`

Comment: It only worked in firefox for me. I did parseInt(self0.elem.value) in the onkey up function which koolkabin told me. Is this incorrect?

Comment: Do as Jonathan suggested and use the radix of 10 `self0.elem.value = parseInt(self0.elem.value, 10);`

Comment: Nope still hasn't worked. I realised it didn't really work in firefox because if you enter 009, it only displays 00 and if enter 0099 then it will go back to highest number which is 23 which is fine. But spinner is still not achieving what I need it to achieve. I included the whole code of the spinner in my question, does every single selfO.elem.value need to include parseInt()?

Comment: No, it only needs to be called once if you replace itself with the parsed value with `self0.elem.value = parseInt(self0.elem.value, 10);`, there you'll telling your code to parse `self0.elem.value` as an int to remove the leading 0's and then set `self0.elem.value` back with the results so self0.elem.value goes from equaling 00009 to just 9 so every reference to self0.elem.value there after now has the value of 0 and not its original value of 00009

Answer (score 0):

```
//question 2 answer
var input='';
document.getElementById('inputName').onkeydown=function(e){
  e = e || window.event;
  keycode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(keycode !== 8 || keycode !== 46){//backspace and delete keycodes
    input=this.value;
  }
}
//question 1 answer
document.getElementById('inputName').onblur=function(){
  var a=this.value;
  if(isNaN(a)){
    this.value=input-0;
  }
  else{
    this.value=a-0;
  }
}
```

What this does is when a user is entering a number it saves the value unless the are pressing delete or backspace.  Then when the input loses focus it checks and if there is not a valid number there it changes it to the saved value.  Also the onblur get rid of any extra zeroes.  Also, you will need to add more to the part that checks the input.  For instance changing any non-numeric input to `''`.  In other words it isn't idiot proof.